# Need help with circuit troubleshooting, Red LED constantly lights up

Tags: troubleshooting

I have problem with the following circuit below. The Red LED is constantly lighting up, but I cannot figure out why. For the LM339, the voltage readings I get are as below.

[image]

Shouldnt Out1, Out3 and Out4 be high since the noninverting input than the inverting inputs?

Vr is 20V.

[image]

Comment: Out_1 should be low; Out_2 should be high.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out, Out2,Out3 and Out 4 should be high

Comment: RN3 is way too big.

Comment: You have another potential problem - the absolute minimum input voltage for the 339 is -0.3V and you're right on the edge of destroying the device.

Comment: Likely not "on the edge" but over it and the device has gone into protection mode.

Comment: Please correct your question with your comments, and make your question clearer. The title should pose a question/concern related to your content, like "LM339 quad opamp outputting high despite low inverting input". Your body lacks punctuation and is missing words. The images do not correspond with the text. You will attract better responses if you put some care into the question.

Comment: Hi Heath, noted and I apologize for not going being more specific. I will look through others and try improve in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the three pins at -0.3V, which is that device's absolute maximum rating, the device appears to be in protection mode. That is, it is being driven beyond its maximum rating and the internal protection circuitry has activated. In this state, normal function is not guaranteed.

Either add a negative supply, or remove the negative inputs and try again. The device may recover or may be permanently damaged.

Comment: Thanks, I will begin checking at the input side for any errors.

Answer (score -1):

- your main fault is lack of design interface specs.
- with no pullups on pin 1,2 open collector outputs , the logic is invalid.
- the result is thus 0V , and when Q2 turns on those outputs are also driven low.

Start with a design spec, then validate each state and function.

I suspect there may be a far simpler solutions, but your timing & logic functions are necessary here.

Maybe your U2 pins 4,5 are just reversed.

Comment: R4 should suffice as a shared pull-up.

Comment: @brhans that depends on the logic and analog specs

Comment: THE DOWnvote is unjustified